# Should one use the holiday/shabbat greetings that are common in his neighborhood or can he/she stick with his custom?

Tags: blessing, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, tzibur-community, communities

Sefardim say Shabbat Shallom and Chag Samayach; Ashkenazim say Gut Shabbos and Gut Yontif.

May one keep his own greetings when living in a community that is predominately of a different descent (for example, a Sefardi living in an Ashkenazi community or vice versa)? Or should one use the common greeting used in that neighborhood?

The issue that I see is that you should not stand out from the crowd, and doing this might cause you to stand out.

Comment: The Hebrew greetings are not limited to Sephardim. In my experience, most Modern Orthodox, Conservative, and Reform use the Hebrew, while Yeshivish, Chassidisch, and Chareidi Ashkenazim use the Yiddish. In the community I live in, both are used, although despite being predominently Ashkenazi, Hebrew salutations are more common

Comment: "you should not stand out from the crowd": sourcing/clarifying this would improve your answer greatly. R. Chayim Kanievsky certainly stands out from any crowd he's in.

Comment: מקום שנהגו ....

Comment: why does the words you use in how you greet someone? Greet everyone with a joyful countenance